# set style to every item that I select?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have a list of item that I got them from a JSON file, I would like to highlight my selected item.

This is an Angular 8 project.

```
onSelected(i: number) {
    this.index = i;
    let element = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

      for(let j = 0; j <= element.length; j++ ) {
        if( this.index === j) {
          element[this.index].classList.add('selected')
          // console.log(element[i])
        }
         if( this.index < j || this.index > j) {
          element[j].classList.remove('selected');
        }
      }
}
```

my HTML code:

```
<div class="cards--section">
   <div class="card" *ngFor="let player of players; let i = index;(click)="onSelected(i)">
      <p>- {{player.real_name}}</p>
      <p>- {{player.player_name}}</p>
      <p>- {{player.asset}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works well but I have some error in the console. Does anyone have a better solution for that?

Here is the error

Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

**SOLUTION**

```
onSelected(i: number) {
        this.index = i;
        let element = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

          for(let j = 0; j < element.length; j++ ) {
            if( this.index === j) {
              element[this.index].classList.add('selected')
              // console.log(element[i])
            }
             if( this.index < j || this.index > j) {
              element[j].classList.remove('selected');
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: `j <= element.length`, are you sure `j` can be `element.length` ?

Comment: What do you mean? can not it be?

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript are zero-based, so the last element has the index: `element.length - 1`.

Comment: In your code you are trying to access the element with the index `element.length`

Comment: Yes that's it, it's work right, Thanks a lot